# Return of webhook is not JSON (js)

Tags: javascript, discord, request

So I want to get all webhooks in a channel using a user token but the return of the body isen't anything i could work with.

```js
async function get_webhooks(channelid,token)  {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request.get({url: `https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/${channelid}/webhooks`, headers: generateRandomHeader(token)}, function(err, res, body) {
      if (err) {console.log(err)}
      console.log(body)
    })
  })
}
```

And the reply looks like this :

`cx�@�������ٚ`

Please help thx.

I tryed to get the webhook body like url, token and id

Comment: You didn't use `resolve` anywhere

Comment: ya i know but that dosent mater in this care cause the body is total bull

Answer (score 0):

A more direct approach may be to utilize "channel.fetchWebhooks" and skip the URL route altogether. It returns a Promise, a Collection of [Snowflake, Webhook].

[link:  TextChannel#fetchWebhooks()](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/14.11.0/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchWebhooks)